# Does Connext DDS Pro support Nvidia Jetson TX2?

Tags: data-distribution-service, armv8

I'm using Nvidia Jetson TX2 with Ubuntu 16.04 aarch64 in my project. I need to subscribe data from other system using Connext DDS Pro v5.2 running on Windows x86 or x64.

But RTI Connext DDS Pro didn't supply official pre-built package for ubuntu with ARMv8, and from "RTI_Connext...PlatformNotes.pdf" manual, there is also no support for ARMv8.

Is it possible to support ARMv8 CPU through building from source?

TX2's CPU info as below:

`nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~$ lscpu
    Architecture:          aarch64
    Byte Order:            Little Endian
    CPU(s):                6
    On-line CPU(s) list:   0,3-5
    Off-line CPU(s) list:  1,2
    Thread(s) per core:    1
    Core(s) per socket:    4
    Socket(s):             1
    Model name:            ARMv8 Processor rev 3 (v8l)
    CPU max MHz:           2035.2000
    CPU min MHz:           345.6000
    L1d cache:             32K
    L1i cache:             48K
    L2 cache:              2048K`

gcc info:

`nvidia@tegra-ubuntu:~$ gcc --version
   gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.4) 5.4.0 20160609`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RTI has a pre-built library for 64 bit ARMv8 with Ubuntu 16.04 (gcc 5.4.0) for the latest Connext DDS Pro version 5.3.  This library was tested on NVIDIA Drive PX 2.  Though it has not been tested specifically on NVIDIA Jetson TX2, from the spec you listed above it should also work on TX2.

You could contact sales@rti.com for access to this library.